# How to check if a directory is empty in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I'd like to check if directory is empty in Java. But there is a possibility that there are many files in that directory so I'd like to do it without querying its file list, if possible.

Comment: list() can be very slow on many files.

Comment: When scanning for empty directories I found that .list() was taking up well over 50% of the execution time. So finding an alternative could significantly speed things up if you don't actually need the list of files.

Comment: Over an excruciatingly slow network (via a UNC path), reading a directory list containing 10,000 subdirectories once took a program I was tasked to maintain somewhere around 30 minutes. The program then attempted to read the contents of each directory cross-indexed against a database, resulting in an 8-hour runtime. `list()` can be _very_ slow indeed. After flipping the logic (database query first), the runtime dropped to around 8 minutes.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

With JDK7 you can use Files.newDirectoryStream to open the directory and then use the iterator's hasNext() method to test there are any files to iterator over (don't forgot to close the stream). This should work better for huge directories or where the directory is on a remote file system when compared to the java.io.File list methods.

Example:

```java
private static boolean isDirEmpty(final Path directory) throws IOException {
    try(DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {
        return !dirStream.iterator().hasNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one go about if one would want to iterate over dirStream after the check? I tried:
for (Path artifact : dirStream ) {
But got a Iterator already obtained - Exception

Comment: @garyee, you could store the iterator in a local variable, then perform the `hasNext()` check as described in the answer and otherwise use a `while` loop over the iterator.

Comment: You say `don't forget to close the stream` but in the example you don't close the stream? :)

Comment: @jonr, he uses try-with-resources in the example so the stream is automatically closed when exiting the block.

Comment: The problem is that on Windows there is sometimes a desktop.ini file that is created by default. The method doesn't check for only that file. One could argue that this directory is not really empty, but it is empty of content user has created. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @tobidelbruck It looks like for that you could simply add `|| dirStream.iterator().next().endsWith(".ini")` to the returning statement. Of course assuming there is only ever one file in that case. Edit: oh wait thats a directory stream not files for the directory.

Answer (score 28):

```
File parentDir =  file.getParentFile();
if(parentDir.isDirectory() && parentDir.list().length == 0) {
    LOGGER.info("Directory is empty");
} else {
    LOGGER.info("Directory is not empty");
}
```

Comment: "without querying its file list"

Answer (score 20):

```
if(!Files.list(Paths.get(directory)).findAny().isPresent()){
    Files.delete(Paths.get(directory));
 }
```

As Files.list Return a lazily populated Stream it will solve your  execution time related issue.

Comment: The javadoc for Files.list() says to close the stream when finished and suggests try-with-resources (and btw, `!isPresent()` is the same as `isEmpty()`), so something like this:
`try (Stream<Path> entries = Files.list(path)) {
    return entries.findAny().isEmpty();
}`

Answer (score 8):

Considering from [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/File.java.html), [`list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) method does:

```
    public java.lang.String[] list() {
    ...
        byte[][] implList = listImpl(bs);
        if (implList == null) {
           // empty list
           return new String[0];
        }     
     ...
     }

     private synchronized static native byte[][] listImpl(byte[] path);
```

It calls a native method passing a byte array to get files from it. If a method returns `null` it means directory is empty.

**Which means**, they don't even have a native method, to check for directory emptiness without listing files, so there is no way they would have an implementation in java for checking if directory is empty.

**Outcome**: checking if directory is empty without listing files is not implemented in java, yet.

Answer (score 6):

```
boolean isEmptyDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException {
    try (var entries = Files.list(dir)) {
        return entries.count() == 0;
    }
}
```

Similar to @Minnow's solution (but with less method calls), this solution has the benefit "As Files.list Return a lazily populated Stream it will solve your execution time related issue."

Comment: I guess count would load all the directory entries anyway. Wouldn't the `entries.findFirst().isPresent()` be a better solution?

Comment: Both Files.list and Files.newDirectoryStream will iterate the directory entries lazily. Therefore, they will work with huge directories very efficiently. However, your solutions will not work well. It's not a good choice for huge directories.

Answer (score 4):

This is a dirty workaround, but you can try do delete it (with the `delete` method), and if the delete operation fails, then the directory is not empty, if it succeeds, then it is empty (but you have to re-create it, and that's not neat). I'll continue searching for a better solution.

**EDIT**: I've found walkFileTree from java.nio.file.Files class: http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.FileVisitor)
Problem is that this is Java 7 only.

I've searched S.O. for other questions related to this very issue (listing files in a directory w/o using list() which allocates memory for a big array) and the answer is quite always "you can't, unless you use JNI", which is both platform dependent and ugly.

Comment: Directory deletion may fail due to other causes -- e.g., file permissions.

Comment: In fact it's ugly. Hope there is a 100% java solution for doing this. Still searching.

Comment: I'd like people downvoting understand that I'm perfectly aware this is an horrible hack and I've done comprehensive research on how it can be done better, w/o finding anything satisfactory (see EDIT)

Comment: Well the problem is directory permissions - not just the wrong answer kind, but also the fact that you pretty much reset the permissions AND change metadata. Not much you can do about the second, but at least check permissions beforehand (that way you get rid of the false negative - just do a list() in that case) and set those permissions for the new dir. Still horrible, but a bit better.

Comment: I don't think even `/bin/ls` would work because it enumerates the whole directory in order to sort its output.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with platform dependent code - you can try using actual native code by loading a system library and using its APIs.

In Windows for example you have a [Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) named `FindFirstFile()` with the directory name (*without* a trailing backslash). If it returns something other than `.` and `..` you know the directory isn't empty. It will not list all the files so it's much faster than `file.list()`.

The equivalent on Unix is [`opendir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/opendir.html). For your purposes the logic would be the same.

Of course - calling native methods has a price on usability and the initial library loading which should be negated by the time it will save on the FS queries.

Comment: Considering that there's absolutely nothing stopping people from creating files that don't contain a "." and nothing stopping people from creating directories that contain a "." - that solution won't do any good. And while I'm sure there's a more or less efficient way to do this with a native API, the overhead of calling it, will probably be worse. Depending on the FS implementation it's conceivable that the OS would have to enumerate all files in it to begin with anyways (no idea how NTFS is implemented?)

Comment: @Voo: The proper usage is to ignore the `.` and `..` entries. If a filesystem doesn't allow you to get the first directory entry without enumerating all the files, there would be no fast way to check if it's empty, but I doubt such a filesystem would ever exist.

Comment: @Gabe Yeah no idea how NTFS is implemented in detail. Your edited solution should be exactly what the OP wants, apart from the fact that it's native - and I'd assume the directory has to be quite large to offset the cost of the native call (but you mentioned that already and the question is about large dirs anyways so that's fine too). Though you should've created a new post (the edited one doesn't have much in common with the original ;) ), I'd love to upvote your post (or do you get a part of the credit because of your edit?)

Answer (score 2):

```
     Path checkIfEmpty=Paths.get("Pathtofile");
     DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(checkIfEmpty);
     Iterator files = ds.iterator();
     if(!files.hasNext())
         Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(checkIfEmpty.toString()));
```

Comment: Just be careful to close DirectoryStream when you are done (or use try-with-resources) otherwise you end up with a file handler leak.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `directory` `isDirectory()` after all (and not a file) and then, call `list()` to get its content and finally, get the `length` value to see whether there is content, i.e., whether it's not empty.

```
directory.isDirectory() && directory.list().length > 0 // directory is a File obj
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'd recommend editing this to add how your answer is better or different from the many other answers already posted on this old question. Also note that the original question asks for a way to do this without calling `directory.list()` so if you still advise using it despite that, you should explain why.

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this Confusion for a Long time about how to check if the Directory was empty or not 
But the Answer is Quite Simple 
use

```
class isFileEmpty{
public static void main(String args[]){
File d = new File(//Path of the Directory you want to check or open);
String path = d.getAbsolutePath().toString();
File dir = new File(path);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if(!dir.exists()){
System.out.Println("Directory is Empty");
}
else{
for(int i =0;i<files.length;i++){
System.out.Println(files[i])
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to add to answer of Developer. Checking is it directory or not should not be in one If operator, because you will have mistake in logic. First of all you checking is it directory or not, and only after that you checking directory consistensy, becouse you will get wrong answer if the tranfered to method directory is not exist. Just check it. Should be like this:

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    if( file.list().length == 0) {
        logger.info("Directory is empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        logger.info("Directory is not empty");
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```