# How to check all Empty Folders under a Directory in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to find all empty folders under my `E:` Drive. When I run below Code it shows all empty folders in the `E` drive. But the main problem is, it also shows a folder named `MS OFFICE TUTORIAL SERIES` which is not empty,because, under this folder there are three sub folders also.

But the code always shows that the `MS OFFICE TUTORIAL SERIES` folder is empty in the list of empty files. Please help to find out where I have made mistake.

My Code:

```
File directory = new File("E:/");
File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
System.out.println("List of Empty Directory\n");
for(int i=0; i<listFiles.length; i++){
    if(listFiles[i].isDirectory()){
        if(listFiles[i] == null ||  listFiles[i].length() == 0){
            System.out.println(listFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot for better understanding

[image]

Comment: @maloomeister Yes there are three folders which contains videos on word, power point, excel series. They aren't Empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a directory is empty in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930087/how-to-check-if-a-directory-is-empty-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach to check if the directory is actually empty or not. According to the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) the usage of length() on directories is undefined "[...]The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory."

So you might want to do something like:

```
if(listFiles[i].isDirectory()){
   final var subDirEntries = listFiles[i].list();
   if(subDirEntries.length == 0){
      System.out.println("Empty folder: " + listFiles[i].getName());
   }
}
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot :)

What if if the subdirectories are also empty? then what can i do? any idea please?

Comment: You'd have to recursively go through the directories and check or you could use Apache commons-ios FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory() function (which does the same, traversing recursively throught he directories)

Comment: @CSE You could also get rid of the 'null' check. It's just a safety net. I haven't looked into the documentation of the listFiles() method and if I'm not sure that something has the possibility of being null or not I'm always checking it first.

Comment: Can you tell me that why you've used `if(listFiles[i] != null && listFiles[i].isDirectory())` instead of `if(listFiles[i].isDirectory())`  ? 

Because when i use `if(listFiles[i].isDirectory())` it also give me correct result.

Comment: Ok I've now used this for checking sub-directories also.

`long filesize;
                filesize = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(listFiles[i]);`

and give an `else if` condition for this like

`else if (filesize == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Empty folder: " + listFiles[i].getName());
}`

Now it show me correctly. But it also shows an extra folder named `System Volume Information` which is not exist in the `E:/` Drive. Can you tell me why it's happening?

Comment: @CSE It's probably just invisible. The folder itself is used by Windows, according to the [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/282214/what-is-the-system-volume-information-folder-and-can-i-delete-it/)

Comment: I can understand this. And I've find a solution also and already have done that after asking about `System Volume Information`.

I've just match the folder name and inside the loop i use `continue`. then it never shows this.